# Group values by first value of group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i want to group values by the first value of group, but seems that i'm blind.
Example table

```
COL_1     COL_2   COL_3        ROW_ID
A         AA      2017-01-01   1
A         BB      2017-01-05   2
A         BB      2017-01-21   3
A         AA      2017-01-22   4
A         BB      2017-01-23   5
A         BB      2017-01-24   6
B         AA      2017-01-01   7
B         BB      2017-01-05   8
B         BB      2017-01-22   9
B         AA      2017-01-24   10
C         BB      2017-01-01   11
```

The result should look like this

```
COL_1     COL_2   COL_3        ROW_ID  Group
A         AA      2017-01-01   1       1
A         BB      2017-01-05   2       1
A         BB      2017-01-21   3       1        
A         AA      2017-01-22   4       2
A         BB      2017-01-23   5       2
A         BB      2017-01-24   6       2
B         AA      2017-01-01   7       3
B         BB      2017-01-05   8       3
B         BB      2017-01-22   9       3
B         AA      2017-01-24   10      4
C         AA      2017-01-01   11      5
```

The number of the group could also be the number of the number of the first ID of each group or any other name, but must be unique.
I don't want to use  a cursor, just simple T-SQL from SQL-SERVER 2012 and above

I think the answer have something to do with LAG and PARTITION OVER, but didn't find a solution…. so far

Any ideas?
Cheers, Alex

EDIT Solution from @Gordon with a small change

```
select t.*,
  col_1 + '_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,sum(case when col_2 = 'AA' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by rowid)) as grp
from t;
```

Thank you again Gordon

Comment: So `COL_1` defines the "first class" order. Which one is next, `COL_3`? And then always three rows with ascending `COL_2`? What is the logic behind your groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to count the number of `'AA'` up to each value.  If so:

```
select t.*,
      sum(case when col_2 = 'AA' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by col_1 order by col3) as grp
from t;
```

I am guessing that you want separate groups for each `col_1`.  If that is not correct, then:

```
select t.*,
      sum(case when col_2 = 'AA' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by rowid) as grp
from t;
```

If you simply want groups of 3 and can depend on `row_id`:

```
select t.*, (1 + (rowid - 1)/3) as grp
from t;
```

Comment: HI Gordon
Row_id 1-3; 4-6, 7-9. 10 should build the groups

Comment: To make it more clear iv'e edit one line for the next group

     C         AA      2017-01-01   11      5

Comment: @AlexS. . . . The middle solution is the one that does what you want.

Comment: Yes, close but not cigar as grp is not unique, but this is the right  way with a small change. I will edit the solution in my question. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Use division with group size on `row_number`.

```
select t.*,1+(row_number() over(order by row_id)-1)/3 as grp
from tbl t
```

Comment: Sorry Vamsi
,doesn't givre the result i want
row_id 1-3; 4-6, 7-9. 10 should build the groups